# Using Blob in typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, blob

I declared global Blob:

```
declare global {
  interface Blob {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (name: string, url: string): Blob;
  }
}
```

this works here:

```
export const blobToFile = (blob: Blob) => {
  let file: File | null = null;
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    file = new File([blob], blob.name, { type: blob.type });
  }  
  return file ? file : null;
};
```

But it gives me error at 2 places. First:

```
   const [croppedImg, setCroppedImg] = useState<Blob | null>(null);

    <img
            src={(croppedImg && croppedImg.url) || selectedImg.src}
            alt=""
    ></img>
```

I get this ts error:

```
      "Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Blob' "
```

Second issue is when I write the blob on canvas:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBlob(
      (blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          reject("Canvas is empty");
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        blob.url = fileUrl;
        resolve(blob);
      },
      "image/jpeg",
      1
    );
  });
```

for `blob.name` and `blob.url` I get ts error:

```
         Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
```

Comment: Why would you override the existing `Blob` type?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković to add name and url

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: But Blob doesn't have name and url, you can't just add it to types

Answer (score 0):

Create a new blob type with your custom members:

```
interface BlobV2 extends Blob {
  name?: string
  url?: string
}
```

And then use some techniques to copy properties to your new data structure:
For illustration just the simplest way.

```
 const _blob: BlobV2 = { ... blob }
_blob.name = fileName
_blob.url = fileUrl
```